# Why does the java.time.Clock has zone information?

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, jsr310

Why does `java.time.Clock` has zone information? From the Clock you only can get an `Instant` when calling the `instant()` method - which is a time without zone info.

Is the only purpose to have the zone available in the clock to e.g. create a ZonedDateTime like this?
`ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(clock().instant(), clock().getZone())`

Wouldn't it then make sense to have a method `zonedDateTime()` in the Clock class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Alternate clock behaviors

Quoting the [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) documentation (emphasis mine):

> Use of a Clock is optional. All key date-time classes also have a now() factory method that uses the system clock in the default time zone. **The primary purpose of this abstraction is to allow alternate clocks to be plugged in as and when required**. Applications use an object to obtain the current time rather than a static method. This can simplify testing.

For example, [`Clock.fixed( Instant fixedInstant, ZoneId zone )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) always reports the current moment as a specific moment, a fixed (non-changing) point in time.

Comment: You're right. The now() implementation of ZoneDateTime that takes a clock looks like this:
`
    public static ZonedDateTime now(Clock clock) {
        return ofInstant(clock.instant(), clock.getZone());
    }
`

Answer (score 6):

I suppose it takes a bit of mind reading or guessing to answer your question, but let me try anyway. As far as I can see, the `Clock` knowing a time zone is very convenient when using any of the `now` methods taking a `Clock` argument. None of the following methods could work correctly if the `Clock` wasn’t able to provide a time zone:

- [`LocalDate.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`LocalDateTime.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`LocalTime.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`MonthDay.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`OffsetDateTime.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`OffsetTime.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`Year.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`YearMonth.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`ZonedDateTime.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`HijrahDate.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahDate.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`JapaneseDate.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/JapaneseDate.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`MinguoDate.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/MinguoDate.html#now-java.time.Clock-)
- [`ThaiBuddhistDate.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ThaiBuddhistDate.html#now-java.time.Clock-)

The list may not be complete. Only [`Instant.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now-java.time.Clock-) doesn’t need a time zone and ignores the time zone of the `Clock`.

And yes, the alternative design where `Clock` had a `zonedDateTime` method providing the same result as `ZonedDateTime.now(Clock)` would have made sense too. However: Someone wanting to develop, say, a `JewishDate` class would never be able to insert a `jewishDate` method into the `Clock` class. With the existing design they can design their `JewishDate` class along the exact same lines as the existing date and time classes, including a `JewishDate.now(Clock)` method.